# Dockerfile Flutter web for production - not for testing or development

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to docker the flutter example app, using the following:

```
flutter build web
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY ./web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

But it just shows a blank page - it runs fine with `flutter run`, do you know how to run flutter web for production in container/Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy `./build/web` after building. The `web` folder contains an empty `index.html`, and used for adding JS dependancies..etc. The actual compiled folder should be inside `build/web`/.